# Import error: libjpeg.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: enthought

I install the academic Enthought Cannopy on Redhat. When I type in

```
import _imaging
```

It print out the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libjpeg.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But on the Enthough website, it was said that the libjpeg has been included.

The Canopy's version is 1.1.0. The output of `env` in terminal is:

```
MANPATH=/opt/torque/man:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/java/latest/bin:/share/apps/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/bio/ncbi/bin:/opt/bio/mpiblast/bin/:/opt/bio/hmmer/bin:/opt/bio/EMBOSS/bin:/opt/bio/clustalw/bin:/opt/bio/tcoffee/bin:/opt/bio/phylip/exe:/opt/bio/mrbayes:/opt/bio/fasta:/opt/bio/glimmer/bin://opt/bio/glimmer/scripts:/opt/bio/gromacs/bin:/opt/bio/gmap/bin:/opt/bio/tigr/bin:/opt/bio/autodocksuite/bin:/opt/ganglia/bin:/opt/ganglia/sbin:/opt/openmpi/bin/:/opt/maui/bin:/opt/torque/bin:/opt/torque/sbin
BIOROLL=/opt/bio

TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000

SSH_CLIENT=141.211.38.9 36340 22
PHENIX_INSTALLER_DATE=300920111225
ROCKSROOT=/opt/rocks/share/devel
PHENIX_MVERSION=redhat-e5.4
PHENIX=/share/apps/phenix-1.7.2-869
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/8
ANT_HOME=/opt/rocks
USER=xqding
PHENIX_MTYPE=intel-linux-2.6-x86_64
LS_COLORS=
ROCKS_ROOT=/opt/rocks
VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/xq/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/xq
PATH=/home/xqding/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/home/xq/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/home/xq/apps/bin:/share/apps/phenix-1.7.2-869/build/intel-linux-2.6-x86_64/bin:/library/yzhang/bin/HMMER:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/mnt/sysimage/bin:/mnt/sysimage/usr/bin:/mnt/sysimage/usr/sbin:/mnt/sysimage/sbin:/mnt/sysimage/usr/X11R6/bin:/tmp/updates/rocks/bin:/tmp/updates/usr/sbin:/tmp/updates/sbin:/tmp/updates/usr/bin:/opt/rocks/bin:/opt/rocks/sbin:/opt/sun-ct/bin:/home/xq/apps/cd-hit-v4.6.1-2012-08-27:/home/xq/apps/samtools-0.1.19:/library/blast/bin:/home/xq/apps/cd-hit-v4.6-2012-04-25:/home/xq/apps/dssp-2.2.1:/home/xqding/apps/dssp-ver2hor:/home/xq/bin:/home/xq/apps/python/2.7/bin
NXDIR=/usr/NX
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/home/xqding/appsrc
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
EDITOR=emacsclient
LANG=en_US.iso885915
PHENIX_USE_MTYPE=intel-linux-2.6-x86_64
PHENIX_ENVIRONMENT=1
BLASTDB=/home/xqding/bio/ncbi/db
PHENIX_VERSION=1.7.2
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
PHENIX_RELEASE_TAG=869
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/xq
ROLLSROOT=/opt/rocks/share/devel/src/roll
LOGNAME=xqding
CVS_RSH=ssh
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
BLASTMAT=/opt/bio/ncbi/data
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

---

I download the source code of libjpeg version 7 and install it on the Redhat computer. Then add the library directory to the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=directory of libjpeg`. Then the problem is solved. I appreciate the help I got from here. So I just add the solution.

Comment: What version of Canopy are you running? We have not seen this error message since Canopy 1.0.3 was released in June. Also what is your output from `env` in terminal?

Comment: I use Canopy version 1.1.0. I have paste the out of `env` in the original question. Because it is too long.

Comment: I also install the same version on mac. There is no this problem on mac.

Comment: Hi, Jonathan. If the `libjpeg.so.7` is already included in Canopy, could you tell me which directory it is. I cannot find it in Canopy's directory on the Redhat OS. But I did find it on mac's version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the libjpeg version installed with your RedHat is outdated (are you on RedHat 5?). Try and open the RedHat package manager and look for "jpeg". Installing a later version of the library might fix this issue.

Comment: Yes. I'm using RedHat 5. Is it necessary for me to install the library? Because the library has been included in Canopy according to the website of Canopy: [https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/]

Comment: Thanks, peberkes. I install the version 7 of libjepg and it works now. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to fix your problem. I'll report the contradiction to the Canopy team.